# AVAssetReader failing when entering foreground again

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetreader, backgrounding

In my app I'm processing videos with a `AVAssetReader` → `AVAssetWriter` combination.

When the app is sent to the background, I pause the video writing (and thus also don't read any longer). When entering the foreground again I want to continue the process. However, when I try to `copyNextSampleBuffer` from the reader's outputs, the reader fails with the following error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170256d40 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12131 "(null)"}, 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12131), 
NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Is there any way I can continue to read asset samples after the app was suspended for some time?

PS: I also couldn't find the error code `12131` in any framework header...

Comment: are you using any background modes?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Not yet. Should it? My plan was to not do anything in the background, just pause processing and continue when the app is opened again.

Comment: Not sure... do you have a sample project that reproduces the problem?